# Что не так с функцией?

Tags: python, асинхронность

Неправильно написана функция (точнее выдаёт ошибку), но вроде всё нормально
[image: Неправильно написана функция (точнее выдаёт ошибку), но вроде всё нормально]

```
@client.command
async def time(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Текущее время", color=discord.Color.green())

    emb.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    
    time_now = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    time_now1 = today.strftime("%H.%M.%S")
    emb.add_field(name="Date", value=f"Date: {time_now}", inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name="Time", value=f"Time: {time_now1}", inline = False)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

> ```
>   File "d:/code/github.com/MIKHANGO/newbot/bot.py", line 36
>     async def time(ctx):
>     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Добавьте код и текст ошибки в вопрос текстом.

Comment: В последней строке предыдущей функции  (`await channel.send ...`) не все скобки закрыты

Comment: insolor, добавь как ответ, я отмечу как решение. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите на строку которая стоит выше `@client.command` там не хватает закрывающееся скобки

Comment: Нет, так тоже не работает

Comment: @insolor я говорю не про `@client.command`, а про то что стоит выше нее